# Get scancodes of Italian layout keyboard

Tags: keyboard, macos

I'm lookin' for Italian keyboard scan codes.

I've searched the net but nothing that deals with Mac except for:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Events.h
```

But this does not contain Layout Related scan codes.

My questions:

- Is there any official documentation about this?
- Is there any software like 'dumpkeys' running on macOS?

If possible I'd prefer the triple (byte 1: Modifier, byte 2: Reserved, byte 3: Keycode 1) as defined in http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage/

Answer (score 2):

The nicest tool for examining keyboard events including the scan codes is Karabiner-EventViewer which is part of [Karabiner-Elements](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html).

It will show you the scan codes as they occur.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to get an overview of your actual keyboard's codes.
To get a comprehensive list of its key codes in a file, open Terminal and run

```
xmodmap -pk > current-keymap.txt
```

I suggest you copy its returns into BBEdit/TextEdit, where you can search / (re)arrange your findings. etc. …